# Can I config the hosts file for spring boot docker container?

Tags: docker, spring-boot

I develop a spring boot application and build a docker image. To get the app running, I have to add a new line "127.0.0.1:www.hostname.com" to /etc/hosts. I want to make this config automatically when I run docker image. I tried this:

```
docker run --add-host www.hostname.com:127.0.0.1 xxx/name:1.0
```

what I expect is:

> www.hostname.com:8080 = 127.0.0.1:8080

but it is not work.
Please give some advice. thanks.

Comment: --add-host www.hostname.com:127.0.0.1  will add an entry to containser /etc/hosts, it not work on your host machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the container with `--hostname` e.g.

```
docker run -d -ti --hostname myhost --name mytest ubuntu /bin/bash
```

you add a line `172.17.0.3  www.hostname.com` to container's `/etc/hosts`, where `172.17.0.3` is the private address of the container itself, so it is resolving it internally from the container itself and from the docker docker server too.

If you run the container with `--add-host` e.g.

```
docker run -d -ti --add-host www.hostname.com:127.0.0.1 --name mytest ubuntu /bin/bash
```

you add a line `127.0.0.1   www.hostname.com` to container's `/etc/hosts`, so it is resolving `www.hostname.com` to `127.0.0.1` internally from the container itself.
It works, at least in Docker version 1.13.0 on Linux.

Otherwise you can change container's /etc/hosts at system boot using `sed` or other substitution command in `CMD` or overriding the command at docker run.